# Why provide a postscript document?

Tags: pdf, file-format, postscript

I have seen many people linking **postscript** versions of their resume along with the **pdf** versions.

What purpose does it serve?

Comment: I'd say it's a local tradition. Does the job require PostScript knowledge or are tools which give results in PS common in the field?

Comment: Simply put - **human beings can actually write PostScript**. Other than that, you can convert `ps2pdf` trivially.

Comment: Postscript can be sent to supporting printers directly, and is the primary output format of `latex` (using `dvips`).

Answer (score 5):

Postscript is a page description language and therefore a *programming language*. Postscript files can be rasterized by any Raster Image Processor, which are also to be found in some printers as well as specialized programs (e.g. [`ps2pdf`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm)), and as Daniel mentions, it's the primary output of LaTeX.

PDFs instead … I'll let Adobe talk here in their [PS vs. PDF article](http://www.adobe.com/print/features/psvspdf/):

> It just so happens that PDF is built largely on the PostScript language, but it has been taken one step further. PostScript, as I said, was designed to describe a page. PDF does that as well, but beyond this, PDF can also contain information not only related to how a page looks, but also can describe how it behaves and what kind of information is contained in the file. […]
>
> A PDF file is actually a PostScript file which has already been interpreted by a RIP and made into clearly defined objects.

That all being said, there are *no technical advantages* of Postscript over PDF. You can send a PS file directly to a printer, but that's about it.

[This page](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/why-not-pdf.html) shows how gzipped Postscript can be smaller than an equivalent PDF file, which might be an issue.

Comment: … so to summarize, no real purpose I guess?

Comment: Many printers can also accept PDFs directly as well now.

Comment: Yes. Seems like a legacy thing. In professional printing and publication, PS is very welcomed too.

Comment: Even in the printing business, PDF has almost completely supplanted PS. (I work for a printing company.)

Comment: @slhck No *serious* purpose. Common reason for preferring Postscript: somebody has an old workflow that's based on generating PS files and doesn't want to go to the trouble of installing PDF-generating software. A printing company once told me that they prefer PDF uploads, but still accept PS because maybe 1/3 of their customer still use them.

Answer (score 2):

While @slhck's answer is *true*, so far as it goes, there's more to it. If you read [the Camelot paper](http://www.google.com/?q=warnock+camelot+pdf), you'll see that pdf represents a splitting of the Postscript technology. So there's more *hacker cred* to preferring Postscript. :)

Features PDF has that Postscript does not:

- Layers and transparency.

Features Postscript has that PDF does not:

- 7-bit clean (normally)
- Potential for Algorithmic Compression through the use of loops and recursion. A small (<10KB) postscript *program* can easily generate a *huge* PDF document (>100MB).

As an example, [my cv](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=cv.ps) is far more clever as postscript than a pdf would be (logically, it must be at least twice as large, possibly three times).